# Better way to avoid extra work with custom WebDriver predicate

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my webdriver testcase I have to parse out a number from an URL (and fail test if it's not there), but first wait while I'm being redirected to URL that contains a number.
For example, when I go to 'localhost/#createRecord' I'm being redirected to 'localhost/#editRecord/some-number'

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches("#editRecord/([0-9]*)$"));
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#editRecord/([0-9]*)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

    int newStudentId=0;
    if (m.find()) {
        newStudentId = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));  // The matched substring
    } else fail("There is no ID number in #editRecord page");
```

In this case there is actually extra matching work happening after wait.until(...) 
After some googling I came to this variation of code. It saves parsing result as soon as it's successful:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#editRecord/([0-9]*)$");
    final int[] newStudentId = new int[1]; //declared like this because otherwise we won't be able to assign value to it from lambda expression
    try {
        wait.until((WebDriver driver) -> {
            String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
            if (m.find()) {
                newStudentId[0] = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
                return true;
            } else return false;
        });
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
        fail("There is no ID number in #editRecord page or we haven't been redirected to #editRecord page");
    }
    System.out.println(newStudentId[0]);
```

Both versions work but I'm not sure which one is better to use in terms of readability (I haven't use lambdas before and don't understand it completely) and reliability. Also, catching timeout exception in second option kinda covers more cases of fail that the first one

Comment: Why do you use an array for `newStudentId`? If you don't do it, what error do you get?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz there is a comment in code snippet with explanation

Comment: Of course, I have seen it, but still don't understand.

Comment: And why do you declare it final?

Comment: declaring it as array is a workaround so I still can assign to int inside array. [here](http://www.lambdafaq.org/can-lambda-expressions-use-variables-from-their-environment/) is kind of explanation about final declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you often wait for the URL to change, you can write your own method and use it multiple times:

```
public void waitForUrlChange(final WebDriver driver, final String previousUrl, final int waitTime) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    wait.until((WebDriver d) -> !d.getCurrentUrl().equals(previousUrl));
}
```

Or to wait for the URL to change to a given URL:

```
public void waitForUrlToEqual(final WebDriver driver, final String urlToEqual, final int waitTime) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    wait.until((WebDriver d) -> d.getCurrentUrl().equals(urlToEqual));
}
```

Or to wait for the URL to match a pattern:

```
public void waitForUrlToMatch(final WebDriver driver, final String patternToMatch, final int waitTime) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternToMatch);
    wait.until((WebDriver d) -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(d.getCurrentUrl());
            return matcher.find();
    });
}
```

In those methods the part after `->` is called every 500 milliseconds until it can be evaluated as `true`. If it is not true within `waitTime`, a `TimeoutException` is thrown.

Your first solution...

Contras:

- You use `"#editRecord/([0-9]*)$"` twice. You should declare a `String` variable and reuse it instead.

Your second solution...
Pros:

- Exception handling. But this can be added to the first solution simply by sorrounding the `wait.until` call with a try-catch block.

Contras:

- You have to declare a `final` variable.

If not, I would go for something a bit more descriptive like this:

```
int newStudentId = 0;
String urlPattern = "#editRecord/([0-9]*)$";
String failMessage = "There is no ID number in #editRecord page";
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches(urlPattern));
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    if (m.find()) {
        newStudentId = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(newStudentId);
    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(failMessage);
    }
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
   fail(failMessage);
}
```

Besides it looks clear and one word more:
thank you for the clarification with lambdas... it made me think!